# Dictionary (key,value) saves as value a list of object and string, want to access object attribute

Tags: python, list, object, dictionary, key

I have a Key-Value Dict that contains a List of a Object and String,

```
Dict[Key] = [object,string]
```

I want to access directly to an attribute of that object from the dictionary, I'm trying this but it's not working:

```
(generated["key"])[0].pathcost
```

Where generated is the dict, object is in position 0 of the list, and `pathcost` is the attribute needed to access.

Whats the best way to do that?

object definition is:
    class Node:
    id = 0

```
def __init__(self, state, parent, action, depth=0, pathcost=0, heurcost=0):
    self.state = state
    self.parent = parent
    self.action = action
    self.depth = depth
    self.pathcost = pathcost
    self.heurcost = heurcost
    self.id = Node.id
    Node.id = Node.id + 1
```

I generate map this way:

```
generated[n.state] = [n, 'E']
```

And exactly code  it's giving error is:
    if (suc not in generated) or ((suc in generated) and ((generated[suc])[0].pathcost > (n.pathcost + cost))):

And the error giving is this one:

```
...
if (suc not in generated) or ((suc in generated) and (generated[suc].pathcost > (n.pathcost + cost))):
```

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'pathcost'

Comment: your code should work if the element in position 0 has that method

Comment: What does "not working" mean in this specific case? Can you show sample code? There's nothing about this that is fundamentally wrong if the object in that position really has a 'pathcost' attribute.

Comment: please confirm that `(generated["key"])[0]` is the object and not the string

Comment: The exact error code is:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'pathcost'

Comment: Do you mean `Dict[Key][0].pathcost` doesn't work?

Comment: Edited adding more information for those who are triing to help, thanks!

Comment: @rul3s What is in `generated` and `n` before the line giving you the error? One of them is a list you are not accessing correctly.

Comment: Your code as you put it in the Q is using generated[suc].pathcost , NOT generated[suc][0].pathcost -- generated[suc] is indeed a list, you're not indexing into it.

Answer (score 1):

"(generated[suc].pathcost >" is in your quoted error.

That's different than the "(generated[suc])[0].pathcost" you said you were executing.

Since your error says that pathcost isn't an attribute of List, I think you may simply have left out the [0] list index.